# Unable to store values in an array from for loop in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

First I tried directly storing values from a list having the name 'data' in an array variable 'c' using loop but 'none' got printed

```
for i in data:
    print(i['name'])
    c=i['name']
```

Here print(i['name']) perfectly worked and output appeared

This is the working ouput
[image]

Then I printed c in order to print the values generated using loop. The ouput came as none.

```
print(c)
```

[image]

Then I tried another way by storing the values and making the array iterable at the same time using for loop. An error occurred which I was unable to resolve.

```
for i in data:
    b[c]=i['name']
    c=c+1
```

The error apeared is as follow-
[image]

I have tried two ways, if there is any other way please help me out as I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
b = []
```

above your first line of code. As the error is saying that you have not (and correctly so) defined the list to append.

I personally would use list comprehension here

```
b = [obj['name'] for obj in data]
```

where `obj` is `i` as you have defined it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable 'data' is a dictionary.
If you want to add each name from that dictionary to a list:

```py
# create a new list variable
names = []

for i in data:
    name = i['name']
    print(name)
    # add the name to the list
    names.append(name)


# output the new list
print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `data` object here is a list like `[{"name": "Mr. Green", ...}, {"name": "Mr. Blue", ...}]`.

If your goal is to end up with `c == ["Mr. Green", "Mr. Blue"]`, then you're looking for something like:

```py
c = []
for i in data:
    c.append(i['name'])

print(c)
```

or you can accomplish tasks like these using list comprehensions like:

```py
c = [i['name'] for i in data]
print(c)
```

The first code example you posted is iterating through the items in data and *reassigning* the value of `c` to each item's `name` key - **not** adding them to a list("array"). Without knowing more about the code you ran to produce the screenshot and/or the contents of `data`, it's hard to say why you're seeing `print(c)` produce `None`. I'd guess the last item in `data` is something like `{"name": None, ...}` which if it's coming from JSON is possible if the value is `null`. Small note: I'd generally use `.get("name")` here instead so that your program doesn't blow up if an item is missing a `"name"` key entirely.

For your second code example, the error is different but I think falls along a similar logical fallacy which is that *lists* in python function differently from primitives(things like numbers and strings). For the interpreter to *know* that `b` or `c` are supposed to be lists("arrays"), they need to be instantiated differently and they have their own set of syntax/methods for mutation. For example, like arrays in other languages, lists are indexed by position so doing `b[c] = <something>` will only work if `c` is an integer. So something similar to your second example that would also produce a list of names like my above would be:

```py
b = [None] * len(data)
c = 0
for i in data:
    b[c]=i['name']
    c=c+1
```

Note that if you only initialize `b = []`, you get an `IndexError: list assignment index out of range` on the initial assignment of `b[0] = "some name"` because the list is of size 0.